# When calling OpenSubKey from C# application, getting Security Exception error and the application is not launching

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When calling OpenSubKey Registry function from the C# application, getting the below exception and because of this application is not launching.

Application: EMR.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Security.SecurityException at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(System.ExceptionResource) at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(System.String, Boolean)

Below is the Registry key value passing into the openSubkey
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\EMR\4.01.00\Technical Data

And one more thing is, after installation first time I am able to launch the application. But Once restart the machine then when trying to launch I am seeing this error.

Below is the code snippet:

```
public RegistryKey GetRegKeyHandle(String key)

{

key = BASE_REG_KEY + "\\" + key;

 if (MainFrame.GetUIControlObject().MGDIsAdmin()) 
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Entered to MGDIsAdmin");
     regWritable = true;
     RegistryKey rkTest = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, true);

       return rkTest;
    }
     else
     {
         return Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key);
      }
}
```

Please help me why it is throwing security exception only after restart?

Comment: RegistryKey is IDisposable and should be wrapped inside a `using` statement. Try to restructure your code so that it is properly disposed of. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You don't have permission to write to that key. Unsurprising, as it's in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. After install, it was probably launched by the installer (which was running as an administrator), so it was running as an administrator as well. After the reboot, you're launching it yourself, as a non-administrator user. So, figure out if you need write access to that key. If you do, you'll need to run as an administrator.

Comment: @DaggeJ the `RegistryKey` is being returned - responsibility for disposing it is given to the caller. That's a perfectly fine pattern.

Comment: "*After reboot also it is calling by the installer*" -- Are you saying that after reboot you run the installer again as an administrator, and then that runs your application again?

Comment: No I am not running the application as an administrator. I am creating the shortcut icon in the startup folder, after reboot we are invoking this. Here when creating the shortcut icon do i need to create it as an administrator?